# How to use a conditional statement along with np.random.choice

Tags: python, numpy, random, conditional-statements, uniform

I am using np.random.choice to create 2 uniformly distributed samples from 2 provided arrays:

```py
arr1 = np.arange(1000, 5001, 500)
arr2 = np.arange(1000, 3001, 500)

op1 = np.random.choice(arr1, 100)
op2 = np.random.choice(arr2, 100)
```

However, for the outputs (op1 and op2) I would like to enforce a condition so that op1[i]>=op2[i].
Is there a way I can incorporate this condition with np.random.choice, so I still get a random uniform distribution in op1 and op2, with op1[i] >= op2[i]? thanks!

Comment: As I understand it, your criterion would bias the distributions; they will no longer be uniformly distributed. If that's a strict requirement, a different sampling approach may be required

Comment: Choose two random numbers, assign the smallest to `op1` and the largest to `op2`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille that would have been my approach but here the two outputs are sampled with different boundaries. I'm wondering if OP really need `choice`, else it could be possible to generate first `op1`, then use it to set up a lower boundary for `randint`

Comment: @jrd1 you're right, the resulting outputs wouldn't be strictly random and uniformly distributed for op1 and op2, due to the enforced condition. It's ok in my case, as long as the distribution is roughly uniform, without a strong correlation coefficient between op1 and op2.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the condition is not met for all indices and regenerate a new choice if it is not.

```py
for i in range(100):
    while op1[i] < op2[i]:
        op2[i] = np.random.choice(arr2)
```

Comment: This is not a realistic solution if the length of the array is large, or the probability to continue the loop too high